# Sql Server Installation fails after 'Install setup files'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I'm attempting to install Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I downloaded it from here - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062.

When I run the `.exe` and select 'New SQL Server stand-alone installation..' , it creates a temporary file in `C:/` After that the installation continues, until it reaches the point where it should 'Install Setup Files'. After this point, the installation randomly closes, and I'm stuck staring at the SQL Server Installation Center.

Any ideas? I've wasted hours on this issue now.

I had another SQL Server 2012 version installed, but I kept having problems with that installation as well.

Comment: Well, did you look in the log files? (Look for a folder called `Setup Bootstrap`.)

Comment: Just checked it. The Overall Summary says the final result is Passed. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Look deeper. Look for things like `error` and `fail`. Also don't just look at the overall summary, look in the detail files. Unfortunately this is kind of chicken and egg for us - we can't tell you the problem because we can't see the files, and it literally could be 1000 things.